# HTML SIMPLE DOM

Tags: php, parsing

I need to deal with one thing about html simple dom.
I need from url: www.streamuj.tv/video/1a660a85e9a2d02e976d
parsing from source code here is:

```
<iframe src="http://www.streamuj.tv/video/1a660a85e9a2d02e976d?remote=1&width=960&height=540" width="975" height="555" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

A need parsing only this:

```
<iframe 

src="http://www.streamuj.tv/video/1a660a85e9a2d02e976d?remote=1&width=960&height=540" width="975" height="555" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

How to on this please? 
I deal with it all day, but I could not figure

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: except for the linebreak, your two examples are completely identically. it is absolutely unclear what you try to do. there isn't anything to be seen as to what you have tried so far. i am sorry, but in its current state, it is impossible to answer your question. please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try again.

Comment: I think you want to get specific part of src of `iframe` tag. Right?

Comment: @Mohammad yes right..

Answer (score 0):

Using regex you can find target URL. Use [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to do this work.

```
preg_match("/http:[^?]+/", $html, $matches);
echo $matches[0];
```

See result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/55rEE)

Comment: Thanks you, 
But I need a parser for more videos (not just one particular)
When i make index.php?url=http://www.streamuj.tv/video/1a660a85e9a2d02e976d

Comment: @BeFa Do you mean you have multiple `iframe` in page that you want to get URLs of them?

Comment: So when I give "index.php?url=streamuj.tv/video/1a660a85e9a2d02e976d "

So to me it's always a given reference example: "streamuj.tv/video/1a660a85e9a2d02e976d" 

From source code example: 
'code': '<iframe src="http://www.streamuj.tv/video/b3206510ddcec839d3d4?remote=1&width=960&height=540" width="975" height="555" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>'

Get only this: http://www.streamuj.tv/video/1a660a85e9a2d02e976d?remote=1&width=960&height=540

Comment: @BeFa I can't understand your problem? Please explain cleary or provide demo like https://3v4l.org/55rEE